# Отслеживание событий в Windows Event Log

Tags: c#

Доброго дня!
Каким образом можно (и можно ли) программно отслеживать события в журнале Windows? Поясню зачем: есть некая БД, в которую должны попадать данные пользователей Active Directory (не всех, а удовлетворяющих неким критериям).
Написал консольное приложение, которое получает данные из AD, согласно этим критериям, все работает на удивление хорошо.
Замыслил это приложение переделать в службу, но тут возник вопрос - делать службу с таймером, чтобы она раз в некий промежуток времени опрашивала AD или настроить в AD аудит и отслеживать события изменения данных? Второй путь мне кажется более правильным и красивым.
Но возможно ли программно отслеживать появление в журнале новых записей с определенным Event ID - такой информации не нашел. Если кто сталкивался с подобной задачей и решал ее или знает, где есть инфа по ее решению - буду премного благодарен.
Заранее спасибо за проявленное участие :)

Comment: А вы не пробовали [`EnableRaisingEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.enableraisingevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/[`EntryWritten`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Похоже, что это то, что мне было нужно. Большое спасибо, буду изучать.

Comment: Окей, тогда сделаю из этого ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Судя по всему, вам помогут методы [`EnableRaisingEvents`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.enableraisingevents%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и [`EntryWritten`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.entrywritten%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Из примера на MSDN:

```
log.EntryWritten += OnEntryWritten;
log.EnableRaisingEvents = true;

// ...

static void OnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Written: " + e.Entry.Message);
}
```

Comment: Проверил - именно то, что было нужно. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @Timmer: Пожалуйста!